# Cannot get Font Awesome Images to Show

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Working on my footer and I wanted to add the social media icons (twitter, facebook and instagram). So I found font awesome, I followed all the steps but the icons are not showing up. I am not quite sure what I am missing, I am only getting little squares instead of the icons. Is anyone familiar with this that can help?

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <!--<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <nav class="masthead-nav">
          <div class="nav-content">

            <ul class="links">
                <li class="active">Meet Karma</li>
                <li>How it Works</li>
                <li>Store</li>
                <li>Blog</li>
                <li>Help</li>
                <li>Login</li>
            </ul>
            <img class="logo" src="images/karma-logo.png" align="Karma" width="50px"></img></div>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="intro">
            <div class="nav-content">
                <h1>Introducing Karma</h1>
                <h3>Bring WiFi with you, everywhere you go.</h3>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <button>Learn More</button>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <section class="cases">
            <div class="nav-content">
                <h2>Everyone needs a little Karma</h2>
                <ul class="devices">
                    <li><img width="127px" height="127px" src="images/icon-devices.png" alt="Internet for all devices image"><div><h3>Internet for all devices</h3></div></li>
                    <li><img width="127px" height="127px" src="images/icon-coffee.png" alt="Boost your productivite image"><div><h3>Boost your productivity</h3></div></li>
                    <li><img width="127px" height="127px" src="images/icon-refill.png" alt="Pay as You Go image"><div><h3>Pay as You Go</h3></div></li>
                </ul>
                <!--  <ul>
                    <li>Internet for all devices</li>
                    <li>Boost your productivity</li>
                    <li>Pay as You Go</li>
                </ul>-->

            </div>
        </section>

        <footer class="social">
            <div class="nav-content">
                <hr>
                <h5>Join us on</h5>
                <ul class="icons">
                    <li class="twitter">
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter">::before</i>
                    </li>

                    <li class="facebook">
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook">::before</i>
                    </li>

                    <li class="instagram">
                        <i class="fa fa-instagram">::before</i>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <span class="copy">
                    © Karma Mobility, Inc.
                </span>
            </div>
        </footer>   

    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    background-color: LightGray;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

div {
  /*  border: 1px solid Chocolate;*/
  display: block;
}

ul, ol {
    list-style: none;
}

.masthead-nav {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 4.375rem;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
    z-index: 9999;/*large zindex to insure the nav stays on top of all elements*/
}

.masthead-nav > .nav-content { /* ask mentor how come the site did have these only had the height but not the width or margin  refer to: http://thinkful-ed.github.io/karma-clone/css/style.css;*/
    height: 70px;
    width: 970px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* centers .navcontent inside .masthead-nav */
}

.nav-content {
    padding: 0 0.938rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 37.5rem;
}

.nav-content .logo {
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}

.masthead-nav .links {
    float: right;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #838994;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.links li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.masthead-nav .links li.active {
    color: #4c5058;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.masthead-nav .links li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #333333;
}

.intro {
    background-image: url("images/first-background.jpeg");
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 45.938rem;
    overflow: auto; /*to keep margin-top from pushing the parent element down*/
}

.intro h1 {
    margin-top: 17.5rem;
    font-size: 3.125rem;
}

.intro h1, .intro h3{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.intro h3 {
    margin-top: 1.25rem;
    font-size: 1.563rem;
    color: white;
}

.intro .buttons {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1.563rem;
}

:-webkit-any(article,aside,nav,section) h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.83em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.83em;
}

h1 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h3 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.17em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

button {
    width: 9.688rem;
    background-color: #f15a29;
    text-shadow: none;
    border-style: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
}

.cases {
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 5rem;
}

.cases .nav-content {
    padding-top: 7.875rem;
    color: #1d1e21;
    text-align: center;
}

.cases h2 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 1.625rem 0 3.125rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 2.75rem;
}

.cases .devices {
    width: 60%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cases .devices > h3 {
    font-weight: 00;
    font-size: 1.563rem;
    margin: 2.5rem 0px 1.875rem;
}

.cases .devices > li {
    width: 33.3333333%;
    float: left;
}

.social {
    background-color: white;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 9.375rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.social hr {
    width: 50%;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #eaebec;
}

.social .icons > li {
    border-radius: 1.25rem;
    width: 2.5rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1.25rem 5px;
    border: 1px solid #eaebec;
    padding: 0.625rem 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.social .twitter {
    color: #55acee;
}

.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.fa-twitter:before {
    content: "\f099";
}

.fa-facebook:before {
    content: "\f09a";
}

.fa-instagram:before {
    content: "\f16d";
}

.social .copy {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #838994;
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console? How are you including FA?

Comment: The only error I am getting the social media logos are not showing up, but the circles that would be around them are there. Sorry but I don't quite follow your question in how I included the FA. Is there some code that I did not include?

Comment: Based on the code you posted you didn't include FA at all. How are you including the relevant files? And do you know how to check the browser's console for errors? See http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: here is the error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

to include did you mean to link it?

Comment: aaaand what does that tell you? Please post a complete code example so we can also see how you'd including the FA files.

Comment: Sorry about that, I tried 2 ways to load it here are the codes:

 <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Hope that's what you are asking, sorry for being such a rookie.

Comment: Please update the question with your code. Also, are you testing the code on a web server, or locally and opening the page in your browser?

Comment: I just edited to include my whole code. I am doing this locally and opening the page in my browser.

Comment: If you still get the error file not found when using `css/font-awesome.min.css`, make sure the file exists. Better yet use `href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css` making sure to include the `http://`. When testing locally and leaving that out, most browsers use `file://` instead which will fail.

Comment: Where is the /font directory in relation to /css?

Comment: It worked!!! It was because I left out the http. Thank you so much for your help. I don't have to pull out the remaining hair I have left lol!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to host Font Awesome in your site, you do need to include the font's as well... opening the [`font-awesome.css`](http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css) file you will see that the font's should be placed at:

```
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0');
```

in you case, and looking that you placed your CSS in a `css` folder you should have:

```
-- yourPage.html
-- yourOtherPage.html
|--- css
   |--- font-awesome.min.css
|--- fonts
   |--- FontAwesome.eot
   |--- fontawesome-webfont.eot
   |--- fontawesome-webfont.woff
   |--- fontawesome-webfont.woff2
   |--- fontawesome-webfont.ttf
   |--- fontawesome-webfont.svg
```

you can always change the font's path, but you will to edit the `css` file, and remembering that once you "update" the file ...

why not just use the web version like you commented out?

here's a JSBin example using the maxcdn version:

http://jsbin.com/sezezitafo/1/edit?html,output

---

It's all very well explained [in the website](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/#default-css), first step says:

1. **Copy the entire** font-awesome **directory into your project**.

Though you just need to copy the `css` and `fonts` folder to the root of your project (or change the path in the `.css` file)